# How to make everything play on a different pitch?

Tags: audio

Is there a way to make my Android play all music/sounds a tone lower than is normal? Thank you  very much.

Comment: Try this app [Music Speed Changer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smp.musicspeed). I pursued an answer around this but realised you were looking for system sounds too, which would require a) root b) not aware of any such tweak